# once the info is submited, the table not appearing and info not sent

Tags: php

if i click notify button , the message is sent but it is not sent as email, and also the returning page does not have the table again, i have echoed the message and it is there, but cant figure much out

```
     <?php require_once("include/session.php");?>
    <?php require_once("include/dataconnect.php");?>
    <?php require_once("include/functions.php");?>
    <?php include("include/mheader.php");?>
   >
    <p>

        You can contact us so as to give you relevant numbers to speak to.Thank you.
    </p>
    <?php
    $submit = $_POST['Notify'];
    $message = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['message'])));
    //echo "$message";
    //die();
    if('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) 
    {
    if ($message)
    {
    //Get Email Address
        $emails = mysql_query("SELECT reusers.email FROM reusers INNER JOIN repplac ON reusers.username = repplac.Uname AND reusers.username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'")or die(mysql_error());
        //$emails = mysql_query("SELECT reusers.email FROM reusers INNER JOIN repplac ON reusers.username = repplac.Uname AND reusers.username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")or die(mysql_error());
        $results = (mysql_fetch_assoc($emails)) or die(mysql_error());
        $email= $results['email'];
        //echo "$email";
        //die();
       if(mysql_num_rows($emails) == 0){
             exit("No email addresses found for user '{$_SESSION['username']}'");
        }
        $email = mysql_result($emails, 0);
        }
        $body = $message;
        $to = $email;
       $subject = "copy of your notification"; 
    $headers = "From: donotreply@rapsody.co.uk\r\n";  
    $headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc:los@yahoo.ca' . "\r\n";
    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
        }
    ?>
    <p>
    <form action='notification.php' method='Post' class='rl'>
        <div>
        <label for='message' class='fixedwidth'>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" rows ="7" cols="40" id="message"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class='buttonarea'>
                <p>
                <input type='submit' name='notify' value='Notify'>
                </p>
                </div>
                </p>
    </form>
    <?php include("include/footer.php");?>
```

Comment: Do you even have a database connection and a started session?

Comment: @jeroen i have edited it with the header

Comment: Any errors, is error reporting on?

Answer (score 0):

using `if ($message) {}` is a bit tricky, if you want to know the `$message` contains some text, you would try with `is_null` or `is_set`

Alos you may try mocing `method` before `action` in your form

`<form method='POST' action='notification.php'  class='rl'>`

Answer (score 0):

One problem I can see is here:

```
if ($message)
{
  ...
  $email = mysql_result($emails, 0);
}
$body = $message;
...
```

Now you are trying to send a message, even if `$message` evaluates to false and you don't have an address to send to.

You need to move the message sending section to within the `if ($message)` section.

**Edit:** You are also overwriting your `$email` variable:

```
$email= $results['email'];
//echo "$email";
//die();
if(mysql_num_rows($emails) == 0){
  exit("No email addresses found for user '{$_SESSION['username']}'");
}
$email = mysql_result($emails, 0); // get rid of this line
```

If your commented echo statement already gave the right result, you can get rid of the other, duplicate, assignment.

Apart from that it could be a server problem, mail being delivered to spam, etc. but that is not related to your code.

Comment: i have inserted it in the if(message){}, but still same

Comment: @lostty84 What is the second `$email` assignment for? See my edit.

Comment: the  echo "$email"; die(); was working but now it is now echoing it , guess i would have to check that sorted out